# When do we get a chance to re-elect moderators?

Tags: discussion, election

The current election is adding 3 more moderators to skeptics.SE, but not replacing the existing moderators.

When do we get a chance to replace the existing moderators with newly elected moderators?

Comment: +1 from me - seems like a legitimate question to ask.

Comment: +1 I honestly wasn’t aware of that (but I think I was at some point, and forgot).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decision to make mods have permanent terms appears to be based on [this Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/984/should-community-moderators-be-elected-for-life-or-have-terms) question, so that would be a good place to go to understand the arguments and/or register displeasure.

Answer (score 4):

You don't. The elected moderators stay until they decide to step down.

This does not extend to moderator misconduct, though. If a moderator abuses their powers you can contact the SE team at team@stackexchange.com and they will investigate. They moderate the moderators.

Answer (score 3):

To make a long story short, moderator positions have an indefinite term length. The reasons for this are that there are basically little disadvantages and a lot of advantages:

- moderators are closely monitored and helped by the community team which guarantees a fair behaviour
- moderators that go rogue will be removed by the community team and the other fellow mods
- moderators that go inactive are also monitored and new positions opened accordingly, ad hoc
- basically most actions that mods can do, can be undone by the community (everything except deletions and suspensions, if I remember correctly)
- mods typically have to step up and do unpopular things. Not having to worry about being being re-elected is very helpful.

Etc.

There have been long discussions about this topic on meta.stackoverflow, I suggest, as Oddthinking as well, to take a look there.